# NodeSelector does not work for multiple node pools?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, spot-instances

> **TL;DR: NodeSelector ignores nodes from another NodePool. How to distribute pods across more NodePools using a label nodeSelector or other technique?**

I have two nodePools like this:

```golang
...
# Spot node pool
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aks_staging_np_compute_spot" {
  name                  = "computespot"
  (...)
  vm_size               = "Standard_F8s_v2"
  max_count             = 2
  min_count             = 2
  (...)
  priority = "Spot"
  eviction_policy = "Delete"
  (...)
  node_labels = {
    "pool_type" = "compute"
  }

# Regular node pool
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aks_staging_np_compute_base" {
  name                  = "computebase"
  (...)
  vm_size               = "Standard_F8s_v2"
  max_count             = 2
  min_count             = 2
  node_labels = {
    "pool_type" = "compute"
  }
```

Both pools are deployed in AKS and all the nodes are present in OK state. Please note two things:

- Both have label `pool_type: compute`
- Both have same size as `Standard_F8s_v2`

(There are also 20 other nodes with different labels in my cluster which are not important.)

Then I've got a deployment like this (omitted irrelevant lines for brevity):

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  (...)
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    (...)
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        pool_type: compute
      (...)
      containers:
        (...)
```

There is also entry in `tolerations` for accepting Azure spot instances. It apparently works.

```yaml
tolerations:
        - key: "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"
          operator: "Equal"
          value: "spot"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
```

The problem is that **the app gets deployed only on one nodepool (`"computespot"` in this case) and *never* touches the another (`computebase`). Even when the label and the size of the individual nodes are same.**

- 2 pods are running on `computespot` nodes, one node per each.
- The second 2 pods aren't scheduled with classic error `0/24 nodes are available: 14 Insufficient cpu, 17 Insufficient memory, 4 node(s) didn't match node selector.` *That's a absolute lie* because I can see the `computebase` nodes just sitting there entirely empty.

How this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution using pod affinity.

```yaml
spec:
      # This didn't work:
      #
      # nodeSelector:
      #   pool_type: compute 
      # 
      # But this does:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                - key: pool_type
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - compute
```

I don't know the reason because we're still dealing with one single label. If someone knows, please share.